# Cannot pass a const char string to a template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So I just made a PoC template class to be able to experiment with templates.

I want to keep my code as it was done before, so I decided to simply use C-style strings and not `std::strings`.

I'm using C++17 and microsoft compiler on visual studio 2019.

Here it is:

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Human
{
private:
    T1 name;
    T2 age;
public:
    Human(T1&& name, T2&& age) : name(name), age(age) {}
};
```

However when I do that in main:

```cpp
Human<const char*, int> brad("Brad", 21);
```

I get an error:
`no instance of constructor matches the argument list, argument types are: (const char [5], <int>)`.

I even tried that `Human<const char[5], int> brad("Brad", 21)` to see if it would work but still the same error.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not make the first template parameter a `std::string`?

Comment: @cigien Its a PoC, its just for me, I want to use `const char*`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/XfyC2P Please provide more info (e.g.: compiler used)

Comment: `std::string` is native `c++` its part of the standard library that is `c++`

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n5KR1XKyyKJmVPLN). Are you using C++11 or later?

Comment: @UnholySheep see updated post

Comment: What's the `HoldVarT<int>` referred to in the error message?

Comment: @G.M. My bad I used another class variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit here was the move semantic at my constructor `&&` which could not take in the c-string.

Comment: I am sorry no one helped you.

Comment: @BaileyKocin no need to be sorry, I found it myself however I still don't understand, why it couldn't take the c-string by double reference...

Comment: @Alex, this is an issue with MSVC, your code runs fine in a "normal" compiler https://godbolt.org/z/6nRcTJ